# Pyodbc MSSQL database backup unicode issue

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Here is the case. I want to backup an MSSQL database using pyodbc. When I executed below command database es being backed up perfectly fine:

```
cursor.execute(
        r"BACKUP DATABASE [MYDBNAME] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backups\mybackup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'mybackup.bak', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10"
    )
```

But when I declare the statement in a variable and execute it say:

```
backupStatement = r"BACKUP DATABASE [MYDBNAME] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backups\mybackup.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'mybackup.bak', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10"
curson.execute(backupStatement)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What versions of Python and pyodbc are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6
pyodbc 4.0.24

Comment: Strange. I tried your first example and although my Python code completed without errors it did not create the .bak file. The exact same `BACKUP DATABASE` statement created the .bak file when executed from both SSMS and sqlcmd. Did you verify that the .bak file is created (or appended to) after executing your first example?

Comment: Yes it does with the dirst statement. If you do `conn.autocommit=True` before the statement it should work.